# Thymeleaf semantic-ui wipes out icon in header

Tags: thymeleaf, semantic-ui

Can't figure out a way around this...

I have a header (H1 tag) whose value is dependent on a variable. This header also has an icon in it. The following code displays the header text, but the icon is gone. I can understand why... the th:text is replacing everything in the tag. Is there a way to keep the icon and have a dynamic header?

Here is the code:

```
<h1 class="ui header" th:text="${'Widget ' +widget.id}"><i class=" ui grey cog icon"></i>Default Text</h1>
```

If I remove the th:text="${'Widget ' +widget.id}" piece the icon comes back.

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Keith

Comment: Have you tried to put the icon tags in the th:text attribute? I mean all the content in the <h1> tags. I don't know if it's the best practice but it may work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `th:text` attribute will replace everything in the body of the `<h1>` tag.

You can put the text in a separate `<span>` instead:

```
<h1 class="ui header"><span th:text="${'Widget ' +widget.id}"></span><i class=" ui grey cog icon"></i>Default Text</h1>
```

Comment: Wim thanks for your help!

However the layout is off with the span tag. 

There is a line break when the span tag is used. 

See here in a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/6rmzcde8/

Comment: This is because `.ui.header > .icon` has a `display` style of `table-cell`. Override the style to be `inline` and it should be ok.

Comment: Awesome worked great!
 the final code was...
    <h1 class="ui header" align="center"><i class=" ui grey cog icon" style="display: inline;"></i><span th:text="${'Widget ' +widget.id}">Default</span></h1> 
If you like update the answer.